# error: bad receiver type 'float' redFloatValue = [redFloatValue redComponent];

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am working `Lightproperties(Color class)` in `CocoaFramework` on mac os x. i want to create a bundle file from `LightProperties.m`, `extconf.rb`, `LightProperties.h`.

I receive this error:

> error: bad receiver type 'float' redFloatValue = [redFloatValue
>   redComponent];

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Looks like [redFloatValue redComponent] is not float. try to assign it to another variable.  let redComponentOfTheColor = [redFloatValue redComponent];  or  let redComponentOfTheColor = [hereComesTheColor redComponent];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code fragment:

```
redFloatValue = [redFloatValue redComponent];
```

You are using the variable `redFloatValue` on the RHS in a position as the *receiver* of a message where a value of type `NSColor *` is (probably) required, and on the LHS where a variable of type `CGFloat` is (probably) required. A variable cannot be both these types, so one of the uses is wrong and the error message you show indicates it is the RHS one.

The *(probably)*'s above are because you've given so little information I can only guess what the types in your code actually are.

HTH

Comment: Thanks - CRD . I missed NSColor variable on RHS . Now its works fine